# Recurring email with reminder

Tags: power-automate

I am quite new on power automate tool (started today) and I have a task that I am trying to accomplish but I can't because I don't have so much experience on that so I will describe below:

1 - I need to send recurring emails every friday 8am with an attachement for some email adressess

ps: this part I have already done as you can see on the link
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8x79.jpg)

2 - After 72 hours(monday 8am) the people that didn't reply would receive another e-mail asking for the answer.

Can you people from the community help em with that ?

Thanks all and have a nice day :grinning_face_with_big_eyes:

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

To do this automatically would require that the response is stored somewhere that can be accessed by Power Automate, then write another timed flow which filters for the response (or lack of it).

Comment: Perfect now I need that somewhere hahaha logically I know that but how to achieve ?

Comment: This is not even an answer, this is more of a comment.

Comment: @RyogaPunk If you create a field that updates when there is a response, then the next workflow can filter out which have the response, and only send to the others.